# periodic exponential sum

Tags: calculus

I can prove that a single exponential cannot be periodic (unless the exponent is periodic) but I am having trouble rigorously showing that this particular function $3\mathrm{e}^{x^2+5x-9}$  $-8\mathrm{e}^{-x^3-5/x-9}$ +$\mathrm{e}^{2x-9\sqrt{x}}$ is not periodic. Can anyone help? (I can graph it an see but I would like an analytical method based on the definition of a periodic function so I can apply it to other functions)

Comment: It's continuous and tends to $\infty$ as $x$ grows.  Show that this is enough to imply that it can't be periodic.

Comment: Lulu had the exact same idea as me. The function tends to infinity so can’t be periodic.

Comment: I agree with both of you. Now suppose I had a similar function that tended to zero has x grows. How could I be sure that it does not oscillate its way to zero....like $e^{-x}$.$sin(x)$

Comment: $e^{x}$.$sin(x)$ tends to infinity  but oscillates and is periodic too. So just showing that it approaches infinity is not enough to rule out periodicity

Comment: $e^x\sin(x)$ is not periodic.  It does not tend to infinity, but it does become arbitrarily large, which is good enough.

Comment: As an alternate way to see that $e^x\sin(x)$ is not periodic, note that it tends to $0$ as $x\to -\infty$.  The only periodic functions that reach a limit at $\pm \infty$ are constants.

Comment: OK, what you say is agreeable. Can I ask if it would be feasible to disprove that my function is periodic by using the definition of periodicity or would the algebra just be too cumbersome ?

Comment: What does it mean to prove it from the definition?  Of course, if someone handed you a numerical candidate, $P$, for the period then it's easy to show, numerically, that $P$ fails.  But it's hard to see how you could eliminate all possible periods this way.  I think it's much easier to fall back on the fact that it takes on infinitely large values and to argue that continuous periodic functions can't do that.

Comment: I mean $e^{x}$ can be proven to be non-periodic by assuming it is periodic with period p (no numerical value required) and showing otherwise. I guess the same approach would work but when trying it with my function the algebra is too awkward.

Comment: I don't see any sensible way to proceed along those lines.  Doesn't mean there isn't one, of course, but the other method is so straight forward I would stick with that.

Comment: Yes, other methods suggested are much better, I agree. Thanks for your time and comments.

Comment: In general f(g(x)) is periodic iff g(x) is periodic.

Comment: Find some value that f(x) attains only once. Since it gets this value for only one x, it cannot be periodic

Comment: That's correct Saketh but how to find the value it attains once ? And what if the original function consisted of a thousand exponentials and the value you allude to cannot be found numerically...what then ?